# Optimizing SQL query on large table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there any optimization I can do to speed up this query. It is currently taking 30 minutes to run.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    service s
JOIN 
    bucket b ON s.procedure = b.hcpc
WHERE 
    month >= '201904'
    AND bucket = 'Respirator'
```

Explain execution plan -

```
Gather  (cost=1002.24..81397944.91 rows=9782404 width=212)
  Workers Planned: 2
->  Hash Join  (cost=2.24..80418704.51 rows=4076002 width=212)
        Hash Cond: ((s .procedure)::text = (bac.hcpc)::text)
        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on service s   (cost=0.00..77753288.33 rows=699907712 width=154)
              Filter: ((month)::text >= '201904'::text)
        ->  Hash  (cost=2.06..2.06 rows=14 width=58)
              ->  Seq Scan on buckets b  (cost=0.00..2.06 rows=14 width=58)
                    Filter: ((bucket)::text = 'Respirator'::text)
```

Comment: The plan shows that table service has a cardinality of 699,907,712 rows. I would presume that this table is partitioned on field?. If it is so, you would need to bring that in the query to get partition pruning

Comment: Do you have an index on `service (hcpc, month)`? Do you really need all of those 9 million rows?

Comment: Please show `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output.

Comment: Without knowing what tables the columns come from, it is hard to make suggests.  **Qualify column names!**

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph What do you mean by "partitioned on field"?

Comment: @Aaron partition pruning is a technique where in a query that includes the partition column, will search for the data in a particular partition, rather than the entire table. On seeing the cardinality of service table(699 million rows), i assumed that the table would have been partitioned on a field such as a date_field or some other column. If its not, i would think partitioning that large service would benefit for typical queries. https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/how-use-table-partitioning-scale-postgresql

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph This is the only query that runs on the table. What column would you suggest for partitioning.

Comment: @Aaron you could think of partitioning on the column that is most frequently used in the where filter on Service table. I am assuming that the application query that hits the Service table wouldnt need all 699 million rows to be shown and would be filtered on some field?. That can be the field of choice for your partition key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM service s JOIN 
     bucket b
     ON s.procedure = b.hcpc
WHERE s.month >= '201904' AND
      b.bucket = 'Respirator';
```

I would suggest indexes on:

- `bucket(bucket, hcpc)`
- `service(procedure, month)`

Comment: What is your reasoning behind creating a combined index on `procedure` and `month` in the `service` table? I am asking because `procedure` is in the `JOIN` condition and `month` is in the `WHERE` condition. So, will a combined index really help?

Comment: @Aaron . . . `procedure` is helpful for the `join`.  If all rows are visible, then the index can be used for filtering as well.  To be honest, Postgres historically has a habit of going back to the data pages, so I'm not sure if it would use the index for the filtering (yet).

Answer (score 0):

Query optimization is something that doesn't have super hard and fast rules, it's more of a trial and error thing. Sometimes you will try a technique and it will work really well, but then the same technique will have little to no effect on another query. That being said, here are a couple of things that I would try to get you started.

1. Instead of `SELECT *`, list out the column names that you need. If you need all of both tables, still list them out.
2. Are there any numeric columns that you can use in your `WHERE` clause to do some preliminary filtering? Comparing only string data types is almost always a pain point in query optimization.
3. Look at the existing indexes on the table and see if any changes need to be made. Indexes can have a huge impact on query performance, both positive and negative depending on setup.

Again, it's all trial and error, these are just a couple of places to start.